# How can I move the Splash screen with touch

Tags: java, android-studio

My splash screen diseapear after 2 seconds but I want it to diseapear also after a screen touch
Like if I press screen I moved next page without waiting until the end of the timer.
Is it possible??

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

    Handler handler;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splashfile);

                    handler=new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class));
                            finish();
                        }
                    },2000);
            }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tes it is possible, you can add a touch listener to your layout that do the same as what will happen after two seconds , some thing like that

```
findViewById(R.id.myLayout).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class));
                            finish();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

**EDIT :**
or you can instead add the next code outside onCeate method if the layout don't receive the touch event:

```
@Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class));
        finish();
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }
```

Comment: I put my layout name splashfile in findViewById(R.id.myLayout) but the touch listener still doesnt work

Comment: do you mean that no thing happen when you touch , or you got an error

Comment: Okay, so it is because the views in front of the layout are handling the touch event , and the layout don't receive the touch event , so instead you can remove the first code and add the next one outside the onCreate method

Comment: @Antoine glad to help you